# How to get number of emails sent daily via Exchange Server 2013

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

I'm writing a powershell script that queries our Exchange server for the **daily** number of **SENT** emails over a list of several days.

I would like to output the results in an excel file so I can do so more analysis (pivot tables etc).

The issue I have is I'm hard coding several days but want this to be flexible to run it over several months.

```
$StartTime = (Get-Date -Hour 00 -Minute 00 -Second 00).AddDays(-7),
$EndTime = (Get-Date -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59).AddDays(-1),

ForEach ($Email in $FilterArr) {
    $MTL = Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start $StartTime -End $EndTime -EventId SEND -ResultSize Unlimited -Sender $Email.Email

    [Int]$Day0Mail = ($MTL | Where-Object {($_.Timestamp -gt $ArrayStartDates[0]) -And ($_.Timestamp -lt (Get-Date $ArrayStartDates[0] -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59))}).Count
    [Int]$Day1Mail = ($MTL | Where-Object {($_.Timestamp -gt $ArrayStartDates[1]) -And ($_.Timestamp -lt (Get-Date $ArrayStartDates[1] -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59))}).Count
    ...

    $MailObj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property ([Ordered]@{
                Name = $Email.Name
                Email = $Email.Email
                [String]$ArrayStartDates[0].ToShortDateString() = $Day0Mail
                [String]$ArrayStartDates[1].ToShortDateString() = $Day1Mail
                ....

    $ReportArr += $MailObj
}

$ReportArr | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $ReportPath -Force
```

Comment: ...what's the question?

Comment: The bit that says hard coding for several days, I want to set StartTime to -180 days and it to "Just Work" TM

Comment: Try changing the `-7` to `-180`..?

Comment: And then I have to write 180 lines of [Int]$Day0Mail =, [Int]$Day1Mail =, [Int]$Day2Mail =, [Int]$Day3Mail = ??? And then how to put these numbers into the $MailObj and concatenate to easily output via Excel/CSV.

Comment: Aha! And now your requirements have become clearer! As the current answer suggests: you need a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options. You could just put a `Param()` block around these:

```
Param(
    $StartTime = (Get-Date -Hour 00 -Minute 00 -Second 00).AddDays(-7),
    $EndTime = (Get-Date -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59).AddDays(-1)
)
```

Which would keep your defaults but if you wanted to override them you would run your script like this:

```
.\YourScript.ps1 -StartTime 01/02/2017 -EndTime (get-date)
```

Or if you just want to flexible on the number of days previous it gathers data for, add a Param block like this above your existing code:

```
Param($Days = 7)
```

And then change this line as follows:

```
$StartTime = (Get-Date -Hour 00 -Minute 00 -Second 00).AddDays(-$Days)
```

And again, run the script like this:

```
.\YourScript.ps1 -Days 180
```

Or, if you don't want to do this using parameters, you could use the `$Days` solution but with `Read-Host` instead:

```
$Days = Read-Host "How many days history do you want?"
$StartTime = (Get-Date -Hour 00 -Minute 00 -Second 00).AddDays(-$Days)
```

---

Per the comments, to deal with the other duplicating parts of your code, make sure you have a `$Days` parameter and then you could add an inner `ForEach` loop like this:

```
$MailObj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property ([Ordered]@{
            Name = $Email.Name
            Email = $Email.Email
        })

0..$Days | ForEach-Object {
    $DayMail = 0
    $Day = $_
    [int]$DayMail = ($MTL | Where-Object {($_.Timestamp -gt $ArrayStartDates[$Day]) -And ($_.Timestamp -lt (Get-Date $ArrayStartDates[$Day] -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59))}).Count
    $MailObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ($ArrayStartDates[$Day].ToShortDateString()) -Value $DayMail
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry Mark but the point is to automate the [Int]$Day0Mail, [Int]$Day1Mail, [Int]$Day2Mail, [Int]$Day3Mail etc

Comment: OK, just needs a simple loop, i'll amend the answer.

Comment: Added a potential solution but it's untested. Try it and see, i'll need to mock up a POC to test it my side.

Comment: Your code didn't show how `$ArrayStartDates` was populated but i've made an assumption. It's worth also noting there might be a more elegant solution than this, but i'm working within the constraints of your existing script to (hopefully) make it easier to understand.

Comment: Afraid it just outputs 1 day

Comment: You're welcome :) be great if you could upvote also, if it helped you. Also if there was a bug in my solution feel free to edit in the fix.